# New and Learning: trying to combine rows in a data set

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, aggregate, row

I have a data set that kind of looks like this

| id | activeMin | sleepHr | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 04 | 2016/04/19 |
| 1 | 1 | 03 | 2016/04/19 |
| 1 | 1 | 05 | 2016/04/14 |
| 1 | 1 | 05 | 2016/04/14 |
| 2 | 1 | 04 | 2016/04/19 |
| 2 | 1 | 03 | 2016/04/19 |
| 2 | 1 | 05 | 2016/04/14 |
| 2 | 1 | 05 | 2016/04/14 |

I can't figure out how to easily combine the rows based on date and id, I want rows that have the same id and date to have the dum of the active and sleep columns.

I tried this but cannot figure out how to aggregate/group both date and Id fields.

```
SELECT SUM(sleepHr),
  SUM(activeMin),
  id,
  date
 FROM table 
 Group By id
```

Comment: add the date to the group by

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include both `id` and `date` in your `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
  id,
  date,
  SUM(sleepHr) AS totalSleepHr,
  SUM(activeMin) AS totalActiveMin
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  id,
  date;
```